# php retrieving id of the last record inserted and insert it in another table

Tags: php, lastinsertid

I'm trying to retrieve the id of the last record inserted in the table 'authors' and insert the retrieved id in the 'articles' table; here's my code:

```
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[title]);
$body = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[body]);
$category = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[category]);

$insert_author="INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES ('$title')";
$select_author= mysql_query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");

$authId = mysql_fetch_array($select_author);
$query="INSERT INTO articles (body, date, category, auth_id) VALUES ('$body', '$date_now', '$category', '$authId')";
```

this doesn't work...

Any idea please?

Thanks in Advance

Mauro

Comment: "It doesn't work" is insufficient information.  what debugging have you done?  What, exactly, isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last insert id with **[`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)**

```
$insert_author="INSERT INTO authors (name) VALUES ('$title')";
mysql_query($insert_author) or die(mysql_error());

$authId = mysql_insert_id();

$query="INSERT INTO articles (body, date, category, auth_id) VALUES
('$body', '$date_now', '$category', '$authId')";
```

**Note** that you were missing `mysql_query` function for insert query, i have added that also in code above.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly doesn't work. Do the `$authId` contains the expected value? Did you dump it to check?

Apart from that, you forgot the second `mysql_query()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try  [mysql-insert-id](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the name says, `mysql_fetch_array($select_author)` returns an array so you will need to get the specific value in that array to insert in the other table.